# Mysql Server Is restarting again and again due to High Memory usage

Tags: magento-1.9, database, server-setup

I have 4 vCPU and 6GB of memory in my server and red hat Linux distro with magento 1 configured and was working well suddenly it started to restart mysql server again and again. I checked the usage CPU usage of all the 4 cores goes to 100% most of the time and Memory consumption slowly went to 5.87GB then server kills the mysql server and again Memory went to 1.2Gb usage and Mysql server starts again and again same thing happens. I checked the my.cnf file and found these settings

```
   #
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
max_allowed_packet=1073741824
max_allowed_packet=1073741824
sql_mode=NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err
performance-schema=0
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
open_files_limit=50000
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728
```

I didn't get what I am missing here, that letting consume my 100% of memory by mysqld process.

Comment: are you sure memory taken by mysql process? do you have `top` output, or system messages log saying who takes memory and why mysql was killed

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @MagenX Yes i have top output all of the processes at top when sort by memory are of Mysql users'

Comment: i wonder if you have memory leak or mysql data over 6Gb

Comment: @ManishKumar Please post TEXT results of first page of a simple OS top or htop report. Could you post last 400 lines of your error log after abnormal shutdown?  And other information requested yesterday to allow server workload tuning analysis.